# What are Lord Shiva's Weaponry?

Tags: shiva, weapon

What are Lord Shiva's Weaponry?

Answer (score 2):

The three akshaya - tuners/quivers of Lord Shiva The three quivers of Lord Shiva contain: 1. Unlimited Arrows 2. Unlimited Divya Astras(like the Maheswara Astra) 3. Unlimited weapons

Ekasha Gada: The mace of Lord Shiva. One blow is equal to a million elephants.

Jayantha Vel: A spear which contains the power of the third eye of Lord Shiva.

Pinaka: The powerful bow of Lord Shiva which is able to destroy creation.

Maheshwara Chakra: The Chakra of Lord Shiva (like the Sudarshana Chakra).

Shiva-Kavach: The armour of Lord Shiva which will make its wielder invincible

Shiva Kaakam: A unconquerable weapon of Lord Shiva

Shiva Vajra: 100 times the power of Indra's Vajra

Chandrahas: The personal weapon of Lord Shiva

Girish: A special sword with unique characteristics.

Jaivardhan: A shield of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva.

The arrow of Shiva: It can destroy creation. Goes Back to the quiver after being used.

Trishul: The trident of Lord Shiva. Destroys everything in its way. Can only be stopped by Lord Shiva.

Tripurajit Viman: The golden chariot which Lord Shiva uses.It can go anywhere, anytime, anyhow.

Yogesha Nadam: The conch of Lord Shiva.

Parashu: The battle-axe of Lord Shiva.

Shiva Parham: A long noose which even Gods can't escape from.

Three swords of Lord Shiva: The different swords are equipped with the Shiva-Kavach of Lord Shiva.

The three teen - Baan Three arrows. One arrow marks all that should be destroyed in battle.The other arrow marks all that should be protected in battle. The last arrow destroys all that is marked to be destroyed. All of them then go back to the quiver.

TROOPS OF LORD SHIVA

GANAS: The head of Ganas is Lord Ganesh. Lord Shiva has 1000 akshauhinis of Ganas. One akahauhini has 21870 war elephants, 21870 chariots each containing 4 men, 65610 cavalry and 65610 footmen.

DEVAS: The Head of the Devas is Lord Muruga and Indra. It is estimated that there is about 3,000,000,000 Devas.

Lord Shiva's Mounts are: Nandikeshwarar - The bull of Lord Shiva; Snakes - Snakes are also considered as Lord Shiva's Mounts; Tigers - Tigers are one of the favourite animals of Lord Shiva; The four divine horses - There are 4 particular horses that Lord Shiva uses to move his Chariot. The can go anywhere at will and turn by just thinking.

These are main leaders of Lord Shiva's troops: Lord Karthikeya, Lord Ganesh, Lord Virabha, Lord Veerabhathrar, Lord Indra.

Lord Shiva cannot be equalled in warfare.

Lord Shiva is one of the most powerful illusionists and is able to trap enemies easily with Maya Vidhya.

Comment: Nice answer.You should also post the source from which you have gathered the info.

Answer (score 1):

**Trishula**

> Trishula, the trident of the Hindu deity Shiva, stylized by some as
>   used as a missile weapon and often included a crossed stabilizer to
>   facilitate flight when thrown. Considered to be the most powerful
>   weapon.

**Pashupata**

> The Pashupatastra (IAST: Pāśupatāstra, sanskrit: पाशुपतास्त्र), in
>   Hindu History, is an irresistible and most destructive personal weapon
>   of Shiva, Kali and Adi Para Sakthi discharged by the mind, the eyes,
>   words, or a bow. Never to be used against lesser enemies or by lesser
>   warriors, the Pashupatastra is capable of destroying creation and
>   vanquishing all beings.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupatastra)

**Parashu**

> The parashu (Sanskrit: paraṣu) is an Indian battle-axe. It is
>   generally wielded with two hands but could also be used with only one.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axe)

**Pinaka**

> Pinaka is the name of the divine bow (dhanush) wielded by Lord Shiv. 8
>   meter in height.

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Dhanush)